# How can I change a column name from a SQL table on a running asp.net website?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have created a website with ASP.NET which is connected to a SQL database.

The website shows a table of this with the help of a grid view.

My target is that the user can add to this table a Column and give this a name.
That with the help of a TextBox and a button.

I am so far that I can add the table a column with a button click but I don't know how I can give the column a name with the TextBox

```
private void disp_data()
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select * from table1";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);                                                
    da.Fill(dt);
    GridView3.DataSource = dt;
    GridView3.DataBind();
}
```

---Try1

```
protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;         
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD '"+TextBox3.Text+"' VARCHAR(50) NULL;";            
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    disp_data();
}
```

---Try2

```
protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    string Columnname = Convert.ToString(TextBox3.Text);
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD @CName VARCHAR(50)   NULL;";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(@"CName", Columnname);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    disp_data();
}

protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;         
    cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD NewColumn VARCHAR(50)        NULL;";            
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    disp_data();
}                           // This works
```

---Try1

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Incorrect syntax near 'Textboxcontent'."

---Try2

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Incorrect syntax near '@CName'."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to add "Replace" to make @CNAME useful,
now it works

protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
                SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;         
        cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD @CNAME VARCHAR(50) NULL;";
        cmd.CommandText = cmd.CommandText.Replace("@CNAME", TextBox3.Text);
       // cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", TextBox3.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        disp_data();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't suggest Try 1 since is is vulnerable to an SQL Injection.
Try 2 didn't work because you use a verbatim string instead of using `@CName` as string.

```cs
protected void AddRow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

  SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.CommandText = "ALTER TABLE table1 ADD @CName VARCHAR(50)   NULL;";
  cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CName", TextBox3.Text);
  cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the fast answer but when I do it like this it show me again: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: "Falsche Syntax in der Nähe von '@CName'."

Comment: For all queries, it is a good idea to use SQL parameters. But unfortunately SQL Server does not allow variables in DDL queries. This is one of the cases where you have to stick with the "Replace" method.